# Efficient coding help

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently writing code in C++ to find all possible permutations of 6 integers and store the best permutation (i.e. the one whose total is closest to a given value).

I am trying to write this code as efficiently as possible and would apreciate any advice or examples.

I was considering storing the integers in an array and performing the permutations using pointers within a loop. Is this a good approach?

Comment: There are lots of questions regarding permutations in SO. Please search for "permutations" and you'll get the answers; maybe they are not in the same language you're coding in (C++) or the same structure (i.e. uses strings), but you'll be able to adapt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They already thought of this one for you:

```
#include <algorithm>

int ra[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

do {
    // whatever
} while (std::next_permutation(ra, ra+6));
```

Note that the elements have to start in increasing order (by comparison via operator<), or else the loop will terminate before you've seen every permutation. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation for details.

It probably doesn't give the fastest runtime possible, because at each step it has to examine the array to work out what to change. But it's certainly the most efficient in programmer effort, and without knowing the compiler and platform it's not really possible to micro-optimise the nested loop approaches anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this excellent post @ [Coding the Wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/): [Exhaustively Enumerating Combinations and Permutations in Code](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/exhaustively-enumerating-combinations-and-permutations-in-code).  It has full code and was written by a fellow [SO'r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90/coding-the-wheel), it should be enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming duplicated numbers aren't an issue, there are n! perumations of n integers (taken n at a time). So no matter what you do, your algorithm is going to have factorial time behavior ( O (n^n) ).

In other words, when n gets big, it will be **slow**. Sorry.

There are actually algorithms to do this on the [permutation wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) page.

Comment: Fortunately n is 6, so the algorithm is O(720) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I was considering storing the integers
>   in an array and performing the
>   permutations using pointers within a
>   loop. Is this a good approach?

No, it's not really a good approach. Instead of swapping pointers to items in the array, just swap the items in the array instead. The pointers would just be an extra step of indirection without any real purpose.